# Test DB schema different than production DB (doctrine:schema:create)

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, doctrine, symfony5, doctrine-extensions

I am setting up a test environment for unit tests, following [Symfony's Test-Guide](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/testing.html).
However each time I deploy the test-DB the **final tables look slightly different than the originals** from the production db.

#### That means

- some columns appear on another position in table
- some indexes/keys are missing or added
- some indexes/keys copied from prod-db are unique in test-db but the originals are not

---

I use migration files to build up the production-db.
Maybe I am doing the test-db setup in wrong order regarding the production db setup?

#### This is what I am doing:

| Step | Action | Command |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Remove all databases | `mysql -e "DROP DATABASE prod_db" //...` |
| 2 | Add production db | `mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE prod_db"` |
| 3 | Execute migrations for production db | `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` |
| 4 | Add test-db | `php bin/console --env=test doctrine:database:create` |
| 5 | Create test-db schema | `php bin/console --env=test doctrine:schema:create` |

---

**Q:** What is the cause of the differences?

Comment: You are right! **Instead** of `doctrine:schema:create` I must do a `doctrine:migrations:migrate`! Now each databases look exactly the same. Thanks a lot. Want to put this as a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is that the schemas do, in fact, differ: While `doctrine:schema:create` generates the required DDL on the fly against your entities, the `doctrine:migrations:migrate` executes a series of SQL sentences that you (probably with the help of the `make:migration` command) previously defined.

It's all to easy to do a small change to your entities and forget to create the corresponding migration.

To check what's different in production (*i.e.* what you forgot to add to the migrations) you can either:

- Create a new migration with `bin/console make:migration`. This will create a new migration with the missing sentences.
- Just inspect the changes with `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`.

**TL;DR**
To just make your test database match the production one, use the following command in place of your 5th command:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate -e test
```

This will load the same SQL, making them match.

**Bonus**: you can also truncate your databases using symfony commands: in the event that you change your database engine, doctrine will take care of it (add the `-e` flag as needed):

```
bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force && bin/console doctrine:database:create
```